# How can I get the textContent of an element?

Tags: javascript, jsdom

I was trying to extract a text from a website, I found a lot of tutorials but none of them could give me insights to solve the problem. The code below is returning me no text, it does print but its empty.

```
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

const url = 'website';
const className = 'font-body-sm fx-to';

// Create a JSDOM instance and fetch the webpage
JSDOM.fromURL(url)
  .then(dom => {
    const document = dom.window.document;

    // Find elements by class name
    const elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    console.log(elements[0].textContent)

  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error fetching the webpage:', error);
  });
```

[image]

I was trying to get the value highlighted in the screenshot, but got nothing.

Comment: What does `elements` contain?

Comment: It returns a HTMLCollection {}

Comment: When I take the `JSDOM.fromURL` out of the picture it works fine. I suspect something to do with asynchronicity is at play here.

Comment: Ye, the weird thing is that the code works fine in the browser's console, but when I save it into a file and run it, it doesnt.

Comment: Do you see the textContent if you just log `elements[0]`?

Comment: FYI: [Don't use `.getElementsByClassName()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474)

Comment: The website you are testing might be loading the contents asynchronously, so you might have to wait some time before the data is available.

Comment: What should I use instead?

Comment: What is `'website'`?

Comment: That's the URL.

Answer (score 0):

The class name shown is two separate classes, as depicted with the space character

`.font-body-sm` AND `.fx-to`

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('span.font-body-sm.fx-to');

Array.from(elements).forEach(el => console.log(el.textContent));
```

Comment: The selector you wrote selects all `span` elements with the `font-body-sm` class and all `span` elements with the `fx-to` class. The correct selector to match elements that have both classes would be `span.font-body-sm.fx-to`. For the `getElementsByClassName` the selector the OP uses is correct.

Comment: It returned some text, but not the one I was looking for.